# Error retrieving metadata from https://abc/xyz/idp/metadata and PKIX path building failed:

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, saml

Getting below error in my spring mvc web app:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

when tried to ping the metadate hostname its connected,but on doing

curl https://abc/xyz/idp/metadata

got this error===

curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT.

I have added the samlkeystore.jks file in security folder in classpath in securityContext.xml. And made the jks using keystore explorer tool. But this error is still being faced. My securityContext.xml is configured as in the sample saml document. is any this else for a https connection required?
Can somebody guide with the root cause?

Comment: did you import the JKS in the JVM?

Comment: no its deployed as a war in server so added jks <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
    </bean>